Python packages for flexible metaheuristics
Are there any convenient python packages allowing to flexibly modify different parts of a metaheuristic routine?
Say I have a new idea of how to do a local search in a particular optimization problem (at the moment I'm only interested in combinatorial optimization). I'd like to see how well this local search works with different types of metaheuristics, such as simulated annealing or genetic algorithms etc.
Less likely, but also possible, that I'd like to try a new approach to global search, but use the standard techniques for local search.
Are there any python packages allowing to flexibly adjust metaheuristics? So that e.g. new ways of local search can be tested with different types of global search without manually reimplementing everything?

Maybe this one also would be interesting.

There are a couple of such librairies in C++. For example mine https://github.com/fontanf/localsearchsolver or https://github.com/iolab-uniud/easylocal To work with local search algorithms, favor a low level programming langage if you can. Otherwise, you may struggle a lot to get good performances

If you are looking for something focused on local search approaches, the ALNS library is the closest fit, as you get to define the strategies for initializing/changing/accepting solutions, as well as their representations, in Python code. For evolutionary algortihms, a similar feature set is provided by the DEAP library.

In Timefold Solver (open source) we support configuring the metaheuristic you want through the SolverConfig, but the Python API doesn't expose configuring the phases yet (note that the Java and Kotlin API do support it).
For example, in the Python hello world example, you will be able to change this SolverConfig code to switch to simulated annealing (or tabu search or ...) by doing something like this:
solver_factory = SolverFactory.create(
    SolverConfig(
        ...
        phases=[ConstructionHeuristicPhase, LocalSearchPhase(type=SIMULATED_ANNEALING)]
        ...
    ))

